# Need help accessing a method in my activity from a button in my layout. Keep getting an NPE

Tags: android

I am displaying a list of items in the standard way using a ListView and a [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews). Within each list row, I have a Button view so that I can trigger a delete event. However, I keep getting an NPE when my app starts up and I cannot figure out why. I'm sure I am overlooking something simple, but I don't know where. Here is what I have:

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;
    private SwipeRefresh mySwipeRefresh;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
        mySwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefresh)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_swipe_refresh);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(rootView savedInstanceState);
        drawTheList();
    }

    public void drawTheList(){
        DatabaseHelpler dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getDataCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"data01","data02","data03","data04"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.view01, R.id.view02, R.id.view03, R.id.view04};
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.line_of_data, cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.data_rows);

        listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

        dbHelper.close;

        Button deleteButton = (Button)listView.findViewById(R.id.remove_item);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(deleteButtonListener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener deleteButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

**my_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/data_rows" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**line_of_data**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view01" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view02" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view03" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view04" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView />
        <Button android:id="@+id/remove_item" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The NPE is coming from the line `deleteButton.setOnClickListener(deleteButtonListener);`. When I comment out that line, the app starts up just fine.

I tried using a simple `android:onClick="deleteMethod"` in my xml and having a deleteMethod in my activity, but the method was never available to the button (AndroidStudio wouldn't show the method when I used Ctrl+Space)

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using your custom implementation of `CursorAdapter` and add the button click listener in `bindView()` method

```
 public class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;           
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cr;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;


    public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        this.layout=layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cr=c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

         super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        Button yourButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.remove_item);
        yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //add code
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

use it as:

```
CustomSimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.line_of_data, cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
```

Comment: Ok, I did that and it works ... sort of. Now all of the information in view01 through view04 is gone. Also, I had to change `Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_item);` to `Button yourButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.remove_item);`.

Comment: For every element I want to display? I didn't have to do that with the `<ImageView>` for it to show up properly.

Comment: if the text is defined in xml there no need...it will show

Comment: Meaning, if the text comes from the SimpleCursorAdapter, I have to bind every single one??? That sounds excessive.

Comment: That worked perfectly ... THANKS! Although I am still not sure why my original attempt did not work.

Comment: `(Button)listView.findViewById(R.id.remove_item);` here `remove_item` is not contain in `listview`...that why it gives null....